# How to transfer tables/databases between two remote T-SQL Servers programatically in .NET?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, import, export

I think the question explains itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?  [SqlBulkCopy Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

Comment: I am using your suggestion, but is important to say that the Connection and Command timeouts should be augmented for large tables / narrow bandwidths

Answer (score 1):

I assume you cannot link the servers directly or indirectly and use DTS to do this?

There is a Microsoft.SqlServer namespace that you can use to interact with SQL Server with (see [simple example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMODemo.aspx), I once used this to do a complicated business rules data sync operation between remote and local databases. But that was all code, not a point & click utility.

EDIT:
You can create and schedule DTS packages (think scripts) to execute multi step data transfer & transformation processes. Here is a [link](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/030909.htm) that talks about interacting with DTS in c#

Comment: Besides my ignorance of the acronym, I used this DTS to transfer data between those servers with the Sql Server Management Studio, but I don't know how to do it programatically

Answer (score 1):

How about doing a database backup and restore programatically?

Comment: check out this link which uses TSQL to backup and restore using SPs - http://www.sqlmag.com/Articles/ArticleID/46560/46560.html?Ad=1

Answer (score 0):

Add the first server as a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279(SQL.90).aspx) to the second one. 
Create the necessary tables and use plain INSERT...SELECT to copy the data.
You could also use [OPENDATASOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856(SQL.90).aspx) function instead of creating a linked server.

If you cannot configure the servers to access each other, you could just read the data to your app - using a DataTable or DataSet, - and then use SqlBulkCopy to write it to another server.